# Set Extention to automatically do action on Specific URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I´m developing chrome extension for my own use, that should block javascript, when I enter specific website eg when I enter reddit.com all javascript should be disabled. I´m using [quick-javascript-switcher](https://github.com/maximelebreton/quick-javascript-switcher) For disabling javascript, but how can I modify the code so it only disables javascript on specific url?

Answer (score 1):

For building an extension that does it, there's a very specific Chrome API to do it, [`chrome.contentSettings`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings).

```
chrome.contentSettings.javascript.set({
  primaryPattern: "*://*.reddit.com/*",
  setting: "block" // or "allow"
});
```

Do note that I would recommend deleting the rule instead of setting it to `"allow"`, so that the user can still manipulate it.